# Using apache httpclient how to set cookie for http request

Tags: java

I am trying to set abc=123 cookie before sending http request.

In the response I am expecting the same cookie to be sent back. But in the response I get abc=890 where the value is set by the target server.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore cookieStore = httpclient.getCookieStore();
    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("abc", "123");

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://abc.net/restofurl");

    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
    httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    // Examine the response status
    log.info("Http request response is: " + response.getStatusLine());

    List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();

    for (int i=0; i<cookies.size();i++) {

        if (cookies.get(i).getName().toString().equals("abc")) {
            log.info("cookie is: " + cookies.get(0).getValue().toString());
            }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It worked after adding

```
cookie.setDomain(".xyz.net");
cookie.setPath("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem resolved by changing

```
log.info("cookie is: " + cookies.get(0).getValue().toString());
```

into

```
log.info("cookie is: " + cookies.get(i).getValue().toString());
```

?